# Close a popout?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this cookie popout it will not close when the button is clicked.

Tried to modify some of the code but doesn't seem to work

```
<?php if (!isset($_COOKIE['close_cookie'])) { ?>
    <section class="clearfix cookies_footer row animated slideInLeft">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="<?php echo $site_url; ?>/images/cookie.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="float-right close btn btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
            <h4 class="mt-0 mt-lg-2">Our site uses cookies</h4>
            <p class="mb-1">We use cookies to ensure you get the best experience. By using our website you agree
                <br>to our <a href='<?php echo $site_url; ?>/terms_and_conditions'>Privacy Policy</a>.</p>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Got It.</a>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php}?>
```

Help me understand what I need to get this cookie popout to close when button is clicked.

Comment: Please update your code, it has 2 <?php simultaneously, it will throw error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your button needs a unique identifier - we can give it an ID attribute.

Then, you can use JavaScript to close the div, and set the cookie. PHP can't do this without using a form and reloading the page - so JavaScript is the better alternative here.

The cookie will be read by PHP on the next request, so your check for `if(!isset($_COOKIE['close_cookie'])` will return `false`, and the content will not display.

```html
<a href="#" id="cookie-understood-button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Got It.</a>
```

Then we introduce JavaScript to hide the block, and set the cookie

```
function close_cookie_overlay() {
    // Set the cookie
    var date = new Date();
    var duration_days = 60; 
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (duration_days *24*60*60*1000));
    document.cookie = "close_cookie=checked; expires"+date.toUTCString()+"; path=/";

    // Close the overlay
    document.getElementsByClassName("cookies_footer")[0].style.display = 'none';
}

// Add a listener to the button
document.getElementById("cookie-understood-button").addEventListener("click", close_cookie_overlay);
```

Comment: I have two files one called close_cookies_footer.php and one footerJs.php